# How to allow other machines in my network to use postfix email on my machine? (CCDC)

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

I'm a bit new to networking and am practicing with a team to compete in a CCDC competition. One of my responsibilities is to handle the email server. I've been given an Ubuntu box in the network and would like for people on other machines in the network to be able to use the service on my box to send and receive email.

So far, I set up postfix using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04

This has allowed me to set up user accounts, and I can send email by logging into the different user accounts on my Ubuntu machine. However, I'm not sure how other machines in the network could use this service. Again, I'm new. I've seen a lot of people online saying that you have to use gmail or some outside service. Is this true?

Specifically, I've seen a lot of injects where they ask you to "Add user accounts" so that new people can log in and send email and stuff. How could this be done?

Sorry for the somewhat ignorant question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is very broad. You are basically asking how to run a mail server ?

Comment: That's fair--sorry about that.

Here is a more precise version:

I've set up postfix on my machine. If other machines are in the network, can they connect and use this for email? Do I need to use an external service like gmail or will this suffice?

Comment: Please update your question - in regards to tutorials, it might be better to use [ubuntu hosted ones](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postfix.html).  The short, very broad answer is: no, you don't need external services like gmail. Postfix and other email servers will do just fine, in a LAN as well as a WAN setup. If your emails are received by other servers, thats another matter. Again, this is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is daemon that handle SMTP(S) protocol and using for sending mails only: somebody can send messages to you and you (or your users) can send messages to anybody.

For get access to received mails you need another program which handle POP3/IMAP protocol. For example Dovecot.

As example, you can use next tutorial for configure your mail server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

As result, you should have accounts (virtual mails) for all your users.
They will use SMTP protocol for sending and POP3/IMAP for receiving mails using your server.